# NextJS - Close Modal Component from Child inner Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I am using the Modal Component from [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) Everything works as expected, except from the fact that I cannot figure out how to **auto close** the Modal after a successful submit.

I know I am able to call the onHide fuction from the Modal component like this at button click:
`<Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>`

*Is there a way to auto call this onHide function if, and only if there is a successful submit form the **MailingListSendgrid** component?*

**index.js**

```
<ModalMailingList show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />
```

**ModalMailingList.js**

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal"; 
import MailingListSendgrid from "@/components/MailingListSendgrid";

export default function ModalMailingList(props) {
  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
      className="special_modal" //Add class name here
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <MailingListSendgrid />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

**MailingListSendgrid.js**

```
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    const MailingListSendgrid = () => {
      const [isError, setIsError] = useState(true);
      const [shakeIt, setshakeIt] = useState(false);
      const [mail, setMail] = useState("");
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
    
      const subscribe = () => {
        const regEx = /[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,8}(.[a-z{2,8}])?/g;
    
        setMail("");
    
        if (!regEx.test(mail) && mail !== "") {
          setIsError(true);
          setshakeIt(true);
          setMessage("Email is Not Valid");
          setTimeout(() => {
            setshakeIt(false);
          }, 1000);
        } else if (mail === "") {
          setIsError(true);
          setshakeIt(true);
          setMessage("Email is Empty");
          setTimeout(() => {
            setshakeIt(false);
          }, 1000);
        } else {
          setLoading(true);
    
          axios
            .put("api/MailingList", {
              mail,
            })
            .then((result) => {
              if (result.status === 200) {
                setIsError(false);
                setMessage(result.data.message);
                setLoading(false);
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              setIsError(true);
              setMessage(err.data.message);
              setLoading(false);
            });
    
          setMessage(null);
          setshakeIt(false);
        }
      };
      return (
.
.
.
                  <input
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setMail(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    type="email"
                    className={`form-control required email w-auto text-center text-sm-start`}
                    placeholder={subscription.formPlaceholder}
                    value={mail}
                    autoComplete="email"
                    required
                  ></input>

                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    name="subscribe"
                    onClick={subscribe}
                    className="input-group-text justify-content-center"
                    disabled={isLoading}
                  >
.
.
.

    
      );
    };

export default MailingListSendgrid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best option here is to pass a function as a prop, thus still making the MailingListSendgrid reusable e.g.

```js
<MailingListSendgrid onSubmit={()=> props.onHide()} />
```

And just use that in `MailingListSendgrid` if it was successfull.